# Can I use Cisco Anyconnect with mobile devices?

Tags: mobile, byod, cisco-anyconnect

I've got a lot of clients with mobile devices that want to connect to our corporate network which uses Cisco Anyconnect. How can my clients connect to our VPN using a mobile device?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Cisco provides a special [application for iphone devices](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/security/vpn_client/anyconnect/anyconnect24/iphone-user/guide/iphone-anyconnect-ug-24.html) or for [android devices](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/security/vpn_client/anyconnect/anyconnect25/android-user/guide/android-acug.html). Unfortunately Windows Phone isn't supported yet.

Comment: It should also be noted that you buy one license to enable the Mobile functionality, and it uses the AnyConnect Premium or Essential user count licensing.

Comment: Josh is correct, you will need a mobile device license. Refer [here](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/ps8411/products_qanda_item09186a00809aec31.shtml#Licnsng "here") for more information. Cisco has good [documentation](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/security/vpn_client/anyconnect/anyconnect30/administration/guide/acmobiledevices.html "Documentation") to get started including sections on special considerations for the supported device types.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a guess, but wouldn't a non-proprietary solution (perhaps the mobile version of something like [OpenVPN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenVPN#Platforms)) be a possible solution?

> While some mobile phone OSes (Palm OS, etc.) do not support OpenVPN,
>   it is available for Maemo,[11] Windows Mobile 6.5 and below,[12] iOS
>   3GS+ devices,[13] jailbroken iOS 3.1.2+ devices,[14] Android 4.0+
>   devices, and Android devices that have had the Cyanogenmod aftermarket
>   firmware flashed[15] or have the correct kernel module installed.

Perhaps some training would be required for your clients, but as an amateur, it seems to me like it might technically be a feasible solution.

Comment: Maybe.  One isn't forced to use Cisco's anyconnect clients. I'm not aware of any free 3rd party alternatives, 'tho.

Comment: Well the question is about a Cisco environment :)